# How can I share my RCloud notebook with someone who does not have an RCloud account?

Tags: rcloud

Is it possible to share an [RCloud](https://rcloud.social/tryit/#dnld) notebook with someone who does not have an RCloud account? Does it matter if they are an internal employee or an external contact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share the results of a RCloud notebook by creating a **view.html** URL (that may be messaged or emailed to anyone).  To create a view.html URL, select view.html using the Share icon drop down menu then click the Share icon.

[image: RCloud Share Icon Drop Down Menu]

This is the simplest method of sharing and most appropriate for quickly sharing results of an analysis that may include narrative (e.g., Markdown or RMarkdown cells) and data visualizations. This **view.html** link that will allow someone to see and execute the notebook within the RCloud User Interface (UI).

To share a view.html link with someone who doesn't have an RCloud account, the notebook must be **Published** using the **Advanced menu** located in the navigation bar in the **edit.html** mode.

[image: RCloud Publish Notebook]

Note: for the notebook to run for unregistered user, they must have access to the URL and any resources used by the notebook. (E.g., you may need to change data and directory permissions.)